# Is it possible to add regular expressions (or, at least, wildcards) to list of custom html attributes?

Tags: webstorm, vue.js

WebStorm has inspection for html attribute names and allows to create list of exceptions for that rule. It's works fine, but it's not enough - some JS frameworks (like VueJS) comes with special syntax (for data binding, event binding and so on). It looks like this:

```
<input class="search-box__input"
       type="text"
       @keyup.enter="notifySearchRequested()"
       v-el:input />
```

That syntax is well-known and predictable, so it might be perfect to add couple of regular expressions (or, maybe, wildcards - they more secure from performance point of view) to list of inspection exceptions in order to describe framework-specific attributes.

It sounds good for me, but I am not sure that it is possible with WebStorm :-(

So, can I deal with it with WebStorm (or, maybe, some plugin can help me)?

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-syntax-highlight/issues/3) and this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8057?pr=webStorm)